# is there an algorithm to solve a task assignment problem?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a list of reviewers and a list of pull requests. Need to design an algorithm to assign reviewers in a round-robin approach. After each iteration, the review history is stored(Selecting a reviewer with the least review history won't work.). Need to make sure that new engineers (newly hired) won't be the only reviewers for the upcoming pull requests as they have the least number of reviewers.

At this moment, I don't have any code just trying to find an approach how to solve a problem with possibly a new reviewer with zero review count. Implementing an algorithm with a static list of reviewers would be a problem.

Here's the specific use case that i'm trying to solve:

```py
review_history = [{'user_1': 10}, {'user_2': 8}, {'user_3': 9}, {'user_4': 0}]
```

- if select a user with the least review count, the user_4 will be selected for the next 8 pull requests.
- if select a user randomly the review count won't be distributed equally.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The title contains the word "optimization" but you don't say what you want to optimize.

Comment: Agree. Updated the title. Thanks, @Olivier.

Comment: How many reviewers will be assigned for each pull request?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should just assign in phases based on priority. For example:

1. Start by assigning any reviewers requested for a specific task to that task, unless some max # of review limit is reached for a reviewer.
2. Take all the non-new reviewers and start spreading them around the tasks. You should keep track of which tasks have the least number of reviewers, and only round robin or randomly select a task from that subset for each reviewer. You could also only select from a group of reviewers that have the least number of assigned tasks, so you will keep the workload balanced. Once you assign each underutilized reviewer to a least assigned review task, the tasks reviewer count will increment up by one so it will no longer be the least reviewed... unless of course there are no more less-reviewed tasks. Continue to loop over the reviewers with the least number of assignments, and keep assigning them only to the tasks with the least number of reviewers. Don't consider any historical reviews, as people who are added later only need to get an even workload for the current iteration.
3. Since new reviewers should not be primary reviewers, assign them last. Again, maybe loop over each new reviewer one at a time, and only assign them to the set of tasks with the least number of reviewers.

You could probably keep track of all this in Python using dictionaries. For example, for each task, you could have a sub dictionary containing the ids of all the assigned viewers. You could count how many keys are in those dictionaries to determine which task had the least number of assigned reviewers, or just create another data structure to keep track of the counts. You could also have a dictionary of reviewer ids to keep track of how many tasks they were assigned to, in case there's a limit for how many reviews they can be assigned.

Would be curious if anyone has any better ideas... I don't think this problem needs a super complex algorithm though to get a decent solution.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could just use a queue for that.

- The idea is to have a queue of IDs or the reviewer-instances directly, that starts in some random or organized order (e.g. alphabetically).
- Then you first assign the specific tasks by removing the reviewer from the queue and appending him to the back of the queue one by one.
- After all the specific tasks are assigned you take the next reviewer from the queue assign him the next task and put him to the back of the queue.
- New reviewers could be appended to the front of the queue so they'll get the next task that is not specific but then go to the back of the queue after.

In the easiest form you can implement a queue as a deque in python, that has all functionality you need (append, appendleft, pop and remove).

```
from collections import deque


specific_tasks = [(3, "math"), (5, "english"), (2, "biology")]
print(f"{specific_tasks=}")
other_tasks = ["geography", "physiks", "chemistry", "sport", "history", "german"]
print(f"{other_tasks=}")
queue = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print(f"{queue=}")


print("\n--- assign specific tasks ---")
for reviewer_id, specific_task in specific_tasks:
    queue.remove(reviewer_id)
    queue.appendleft(reviewer_id)
    print(f"assign {specific_task=} to {reviewer_id=}")
    print(f"{queue=}")

print("\n--- assign other tasks ---")
for other_task in other_tasks:
    reviewer_id = queue.pop()
    queue.appendleft(reviewer_id)
    print(f"assign {other_task=} to {reviewer_id=}")
    print(f"{queue=}")

print("\n--- add reviewer ---")
new_reviewer = 9
queue.append(new_reviewer)
print(f"add reviewer {new_reviewer}")
print(f"{queue=}")

print("\n--- remove reviewer ---")
reviewer_to_remove = 4
queue.remove(reviewer_to_remove)
print(f"remove reviewer {reviewer_to_remove}")
print(f"{queue=}")
```

This gives following output:

```
specific_tasks=[(3, 'math'), (5, 'english'), (2, 'biology')]
other_tasks=['geography', 'physiks', 'chemistry', 'sport', 'history', 'german']
queue=deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

--- assign specific tasks ---
assign specific_task='math' to reviewer_id=3
queue=deque([3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6])
assign specific_task='english' to reviewer_id=5
queue=deque([5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6])
assign specific_task='biology' to reviewer_id=2
queue=deque([2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6])

--- assign other tasks ---
assign other_task='geography' to reviewer_id=6
queue=deque([6, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4])
assign other_task='physiks' to reviewer_id=4
queue=deque([4, 6, 2, 5, 3, 1])
assign other_task='chemistry' to reviewer_id=1
queue=deque([1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 3])
assign other_task='sport' to reviewer_id=3
queue=deque([3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5])
assign other_task='history' to reviewer_id=5
queue=deque([5, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2])
assign other_task='german' to reviewer_id=2
queue=deque([2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6])

--- add reviewer ---
add reviewer 9
queue=deque([2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6, 9])

--- remove reviewer ---
remove reviewer 4
queue=deque([2, 5, 3, 1, 6, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay).
While this has a fancy name and is used in lots of scientific fields, this can lead to a relatively simple and robust solution.

Here is an easy way to go using this:

Each time a new request is fulfilled (here we suppose weight lambda=.98, but this can be adjusted. You would want to have decay closer to 1 for larger teams, therefore I suggest you use `decay = 1-(1/len(review_history))`

-first all user weights are normalized. This will help avoid ending up to all zero vectors, and will help early users to catch up. During this, we make the average weight of a user to 1.0

-then all users weights get multiplied by lambda (e.g. times.98)

-the user that did it gets +1,

To see it in action:

```
import numpy as np
review_history=np.array([ 10, 8, 9, 0])

decay = 1-1.0/len(review_history)
print ("review_history:  "+" ,".join([f'{x:<2.3f}' for x in review_history]))
for i in range(10):
    review_history = (review_history * len(review_history)) / review_history.sum()
    print ("normalized    :  "+" ,".join([f'{x:<2.3f}' for x in review_history]), end='')
    review_history = review_history * decay
    print ("times decay   :  "+" ,".join([f'{x:<2.3f}' for x in review_history]), end='')
    pick = np.argmin(review_history)
    print(f'==>pick user:{pick+1}')
    review_history[pick] += 1
    print("   ==> pick +1:  "+" ,".join([f'{x:>2.3f}' for x in review_history]))
```

Note that decay should be <=1. For  decay=1 you basically get your initial algorithm. For decay very small, anything that happened before a few rounds is essentially non-important. You can pick your own balance:)

You can go on and run the algorithm for e.g. the numbers `[ 10, 8, 9, 0]` and see that it works fine, but in reality it should be even better because you will never end up with such in the first place:

```
import numpy as np
review_history=np.array([ 0, 0, 0])

decay = 1-1.0/len(review_history)
print ("review_history:  "+" ,".join([f'{x:<2.3f}' for xin review_history]))
for i in range(100):
    review_history = review_history * decay
    pick = np.argmin(review_history)
    review_history[pick] += 1
    
print ("review_history after 100:  "+" ,".join([f'{x:<2.3f}' for x in review_history]))
```

now add a user:

```
review_history = np.array(list(review_history)+[0])
decay = 1-1.0/len(review_history)
```

next picks:

```
==>pick user:4
==>pick user:2
==>pick user:3
==>pick user:4
==>pick user:1
==>pick user:2
==>pick user:3
==>pick user:4
==>pick user:1
==>pick user:2
```

If you think this is too fair to new users, consider skipping the normalization part and/or adding some randomness by selecting randomly
amongst the last x ones with the lowest score... Tweek as needed...

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import json

with open("review_history.json", "r") as jsonFile:
    review_history = json.load(jsonFile)
total_pl = 0
user_count = 0
new_list = []
for i in review_history:
    user_count += 1
    for k in i: 
        total_pl += review_history[review_history.index(i)][k]
        new_list.append(review_history[review_history.index(i)][k])
print('total user count: ', user_count, '\n')       
print('total pull requests so far: ',total_pl,'\n')
print(new_list)

copy_list = new_list.copy()
for i in new_list:
    difference = max(new_list) - new_list[new_list.index(i)]
    print(difference)
    if difference >=5:
        copy_list[new_list.index(i)] = random.randint(42,50) 
    if difference >=3 and difference<5:
        copy_list[new_list.index(i)] = random.randint(30,50)    
    if difference >=0 and difference<3:
        copy_list[new_list.index(i)] = random.randint(5,50)

least = copy_list.index(max(copy_list))
print(review_history[least])
for i in review_history:
    for k in i:
        if review_history.index(i) == least:
            review_history[review_history.index(i)][k] += 1
with open("review_history.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(review_history,jsonFile)
print(review_history)

# def reset_json1():
#     review_history = [{"user_1": 10}, {"user_2": 8}, {"user_3": 9}, {"user_4": 0}]
#     print(review_history)
#     with open("review_history.json", "w") as jsonFile:
#       json.dump(review_history,jsonFile)
# reset_json1()
```

User4 catches up in about 20 pull requests, and once he does, the gaps between users are never more than 3. But you can play with the value 42 and can set it between 35 and 45 depending on how fast you want your that user to catch up:

```
if difference >=5:
   copy_list[new_list.index(i)] = random.randint(42,50)
```

outputs:

```
total user count:  4 

total pull requests so far:  81

[21, 21, 20, 19]
{'user_4': 19}
[{'user_1': 21}, {'user_2': 21}, {'user_3': 20}, {'user_4': 20}]
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\python>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you request correctly, you willing to send reviews to X users in the system, while X count is going to change. At the same point in time criteria that you have do not allow you to choose users one by one.

There are number of ways get this working, but the most simple I believe is the following (it will require getting data about previous choice prior to execution). You can assign each user number for simplicity.

```
on init
      declare %last_round_robin[128]
      declare $total_round_robin
      declare polyphonic $current_round_robin
end on

on note
      if ($total_round_robin > 1)
            $current_round_robin := (%last_round_robin[$EVENT_NOTE] - 1 + random(1, $total_round_robin - 1)) mod $total_round_robin + 1
            %last_round_robin[$EVENT_NOTE] := $current_round_robin
      else
            $current_round_robin := 1
      end if
end on
```

As you can see, the code leverages the modulo operator in order to include all values except for the last played round-robin without the use of loops. The code sets the current round-robin variable to a number between one and the maximum round-robin available. If the round-robin value needs to be 0-index based, it's a simple adjustment.

Original post: https://www.orangetreesamples.com/blog/scripting-nonrepeating-roundrobin